# Sometimes DIVs are making like a ladder

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension.

Sometimes when I'm clicking on the extension icon, `div`s are making like a "ladder":

[image]

I want it to be like this:

[image]

How can I ensure the currency fields are aligned properly?

Here is my markup:

```html
<div class="calc">
    <div class="in">
        <img id="cur-img-in" src="img/AMD.gif"/>
        <select name="currency-calc-cur" id="in-select">
            <option selected="selected" value="AMD">AMD</option>
            <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
            <option value="RUR">RUR</option>
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="in"/>
    </div>
    <img id='swap-cur' src="img/swap.png" alt="Swap"/>
    <div class="out">
        <img id="cur-img-out" src="img/USD.gif"/>
        <select name="currency-calc-cur" id="out-select">
            <option value="AMD">AMD</option>
            <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
            <option value="RUR">RUR</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="USD">USD</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="out"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And style:

```css
.calc {
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-left: 20%;
   width: 60%;
}

.calc input[type="text"] {
   width: 100%;
}

.calc #bank-list {
    width: 100%;
}

.calc [name="currency-calc-cur"] {
    width: 78%;
}
.calc .in {
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.calc .out {
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}

.calc #swap-cur {
    margin: 17px 0 0 16px;
}
```

And [my sources from GitHub](https://github.com/mike1808/amd-rates) if something is missing.

Comment: I would cover the swap image in div with a width of 20%. The div with the class "in" and the img-div should be float left.

Comment: @arm, it looks like your elements are just running out of space.  [Watch them grow/shrink](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/CaoIx).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand ty for that note. I have changed input width (with currency) to width: calc(100% - 22px);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image likely needs to be floated as well.

```
.calc #swap-cur {
    float: left;
    margin: 17px 0 0 16px;
}
```